# ngSwipe and horizontal scroll

Tags: javascript, angularjs, touch, dom-events

I'm having issues combining `ng-swipe` and horizontal scrolling on mobile. The use case is that I have a page that on swiping should load next or previous and inside there are modules that show a lot of information. Some of it is scrolled.

So, as soon as you scroll the swipe on the parent kicks in and you get navigated. So I put another pair of `ng-swipe` on the parent of the scrollable element with this sort of trickery:

```
self.onInnerSwipe = function($event) {
  $event.originalEvent.preventAction = true;
};
```

And then on the parent:

```
var shouldActionProceed = function($event) {
  return !$event || !$event.originalEvent || !$event.originalEvent.preventAction;
};

self.goToPrev = function($event) {
  if (shouldActionProceed($event)){
    // Do Magic
  }
}
```

This does the trick in the way that the action doesn't proceed if I'm swiping over that element but the scroll doesn't really work. It sorts of but it doesn't. It starts a bit and then stops.

On Chrome there are this warnings being logged *sometimes*.

> Ignored attempt to cancel a touchmove event with cancelable=false, for
>   example because scrolling is in progress and cannot be interrupted.

I have prepared a demo here: http://jsbin.com/webologavu/2/ which is overly simplistic but you can reproduce the issue.

Any hints?

Comment: I posted a very short answer. I would love to help further but I am not sure I really get the issue.
Here is what I understand: you want the swipe on parent to change the page, and the swipe on the ul inner element to just trigger a scroll; is this correct?

Comment: That's correct yes. I want to be able to scroll normally horizontally.

Comment: I can't get your current code to navigate from an android. Is that because you disable tried to control for parent/child. Can you give me another example that demonstrates original behavior or explain what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: It's currently not navigating but there's an alert that fires if you scroll on the parent (big grey box) that should say "Swiped". The intent is to be able to scroll horizontally on the image gallery. @DaveAlperovich do let me know if this doesn't make sense.

Comment: Yes, now I understand. I think I see how to fix it. If I'm right, it is a propagation issue...

Comment: I don't see any functionality to cause scrolling on swipe. Am I missing something?

Comment: There's none except the list of images that has `overflow-x: auto`. If you scroll with your mouse on that it will work natively but it doesn't on touch devices as it's janky.

Comment: I didn't see that because it wasnt addressed to me. Once you use swipe event handler, the entire block (and children) will NOT scroll. To make them scroll, you now have to add that behavior on swipe.

Comment: Take a look at my version of your JSBin. I have implemented a very crude scroll left and right. The scroll can be implemented in better ways, but you cannot unbind or unpropogate the event once you have altered behavior with `ng-scroll` http://jsbin.com/suqeqa/2/

Comment: This would work better with mobile angular UI https://github.com/mcasimir/mobile-angular-ui

Answer (score 2):

I think that it's a concurrency issue with these events. It might work better if you your parent event doesn't rely on the child event. To achieve that:

```
//add a identifier to your list element
<ul class="myList" your-other-attrs></ul>

//should proceed can rely on the target element to find out
//if the target element belongs (or is) in your list.
var shouldActionProceed = function($event) {
    return !$($event.target).hasClass("myList") &&  //is myList?
        $($event.target).parents(".myList").length == 0; //has parent 'myList'?
};
```

This way, the parent event can work on its on.

Comment: have you tested this, or is it speculation?

Comment: I've tested here: http://jsbin.com/vizugayire/1/edit?html,js,output Could not find any weird behavior, however I'm not entirely sure what you meant by "it sort of work but it doesn't" so you might be the best one to test it.

Comment: That was OP saying that

Comment: This doesn't work. I want to be able to horizontally scroll on a mobile device. Which it doesn't work. The "it sort of work" but it doesn't is that you scroll and it's maybe a pixel or two and then stop

Comment: This should be removed as answer as it will be wrongly auto awarded and it doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: sort of work: if you only "swipe" a few pixels, the event is not registered as swiping but rather as scrolling. If you swipe longer, it is registered as swiping and prevented by the event handle he registered. That's why it "works" a bit at the beginning and then stops..